# .vss file is getting downloaded as .vsd file

Tags: document-library, visio

I upload a .vss file to our Sharepoint document library but while downloading it by clicking on the file,it gets saved as .vsd file(if i select "open",it opens in .vss format).

However when i use explorer view and "download a copy' option,the document is saved as .vss file.

What could be the reason for this behaviour and how can i download and save the file in .vss format by clicking on the file?

Comment: To me it sounds like a client side or browser issue, did you tried it in different browsers or different machines ? IE does interfere sometimes while downloading files, http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_xp/ie8-changes-downloaded-office-files-to-zip-why-and/98a0b844-a806-4ab2-a705-8b864e87da54

Comment: The document is getting downloaded correctly(as .vss file) in Google chrome,Mozilla and also in IE9 but with IE8 it downloads as .vsd file. With IE8,all users face the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the mime type to IIS.http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap